# Payment service doesn't work although the response is the right JSON string

Tags: json, facebook, wcf, payment

i'm developing a payment service in WCF which is called by facebook. i'm logging the execution and i get  the right stream . I decode the stream, validate the product and at the end I return a JSON string that looks like this:

{\"content\":[{\"title\":\"Test product\",\"description\":\"This is a test\",\"price\":2,\"image_url\":\"https://godz.yuccastudios.com/images/afexha.jpg\",\"product_url\":\"https://godz.yuccastudios.com/images/afexha.jpg\",\"item_id\":\"1\"}],\"method\":\"payments_get_items\",\"order_id\":\"530567020336520\"}

This always give me a popup saying that there is been a generic error processing the payments.....

I'm running out of ideas to solve this....any help?

Comment: Is this really as JSON string looks like? Because afaik it should look like {"content":["title":"Test product", .....